# Program will not start with Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, boot, speedfan

I just purchased a Windows 8 laptop, and use Speedfan to monitor temperatures. I would like to have Speedfan start with Windows, so I placed a shortcut to the application in the following folder:

**C:\Users\Erik\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"**

There are several other application shortcuts in there that all start with Windows, but for some reason, Speedfan doesn't want to. This is important to me because I have Rainmeter widgets that, in turn, use Speedfan to display temperatures, and having to manually start it up is a real pain.

How do I make Speedfan start up with Windows 8? Placing it in the startup folder obviously did nothing, so is there a better way?

Comment: This problem has been reported multiple times and does not appear to have been fixed. http://www.bugtrack.almico.com/view.php?id=1809 and http://www.bugtrack.almico.com/view.php?id=2113 I would contact `alfredo [at] almico.com` for support

Comment: Would scheduling a task work? I suppose I could always schedule a recurring task to start it whenever Windows starts.